# Angular Inject() function doesn't provide router to CanActivateFn

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to use one of the Angular v14 features which is CanActivateFn.

Unfortunately, when my guard is executed and the statement in return is false, I am not getting redirected. Error is being thrown:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: router.parseUrl is not a function
> TypeError: router.parseUrl is not a function

allowed-entities.guard.fn.ts

```
export function AllowedEntitiesGuard(allowedEntities: string[]): CanActivateFn {
  const router = Inject(Router);
  return (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
    const entitiesTypeParameter = route.paramMap.get('entitiesType')

    return allowedEntities.indexOf(entitiesTypeParameter) !== -1 ? true : router.parseUrl('/');
  };
}
```

main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: environment },
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
  ],
});
```

When I am trying to console.log router, it shows me its function ParamDecorator instance.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was related to wrong import.

I should use inject instead of Inject.

*allowed-entities.guard.fn.ts*

```
// Good!
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

// Absolutely wrong!    
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

Another thing. I cannot use inject() like above in the original post, because of [NG0203](https://angular.io/errors/NG0203). I had to move Router injection into CanActivateFn body, so it belongs to context.

I ended up with guard looking like that:

*allowed-entities.guard.fn.ts*

```
export function AllowedEntitiesGuard(allowedEntities: string[]): CanActivateFn {
  return (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree => {
    const router: Router = inject(Router);
    const entitiesType: string | null = route.paramMap.get(
      'entitiesType'
    );

    return allowedEntities.indexOf(entitiesType) !== -1 ? true : router.parseUrl('/');
  };
}
```

With this approach, I can pass the entities directly into the guard. No need to specify additional data parameter and then retrieve it from ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

*app.routes.ts*

```
canActivate: [AllowedEntitiesGuard(['EntityTypeOne', 'EntityTypeTwo'])
```

Comment: Will second the inject of any providers within the CanActivateFn body as well. I was returning an observable and injecting the Router within the observable pipe caused this issue as well.